# Getting R, G, and B of Active Color in Custom Color Palette?

Tags: add-on

I have a custom palette that already has colors inside of it. I can even select which colors I want, but they don't do anything. Although, I can print out the locations of color in memory with 'print(pal.colors.active)' where 'pal' is a 'Palette' object - how can I get the R, G, and B components of the active color within said palette? I know there are tons of questions asked on colors already. But, I couldn't seem to find another post with this specific problem relating to colors.

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider expanding tags on this question. At least add `python`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PaletteColor.html#bpy.types.PaletteColor) PaletteColor class has `color` attribute, which is

> float array of 3 items in [0, 1], default (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

And `active` [is just another PaletteColor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PaletteColors.html#bpy.types.PaletteColors.active).

Assuming these values are RGB, it would be

```
print([value for value in pal.colors.active.color])
```